# Would someone check my code in setters and getters, just to make sure it is right?

Tags: c#

I'm getting a error: No overload for method 'setTemp' takes 1 arguments

I just need help with alter the methods in the class to work as appropriate getters and setters for the speed and temp attributes. Use the same values as shown in the output below, speed of 50 and temperature of 70.5. Alter the methods setSpeed(), getSpeed(), setTemp() and getTemp().

Create a Car object called ford. Set the speed for both speed and temp using the setters. Print out the values of speed and temp using the getters.

```
using System; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment13 {
    class Car {
        int Speed = 50;
        double Temp =70.5;

        private int Speed;

        public void setSpeed(int speed) {
            this.Speed = 0;
        }

        public int getSpeed() {
            return Speed;
        }

        private int Temp;

        public void setTemp() {
            this.Temp = 0;
        }

        public int getTemp() {
            return Temp;
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Car ford = new Car();

            ford.setSpeed(65);
            ford.setTemp(120);

            Console.WriteLine("Speed = " + ford.getSpeed());
            Console.WriteLine("Temp = " + ford.getTemp());

            Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You always set the temperature to 0... Plus, you don't respect the CamelCase

Comment: Why do you have get and set methods instead of properties? Did your tutor give you the setSpeed(), getSpeed() etc names or is that your invention?

Comment: As for the error, it's plain and simple: No overload for method 'setTemp' takes 1 arguments. How many arguments does setTemp have? (none). How many are you supplying when you call it? (1). How can you not work this out for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A class represents a abstraction of things. Whenever you design a class you should make sure the following(Others can add if I miss anything) :

1. Make sure all your **data and operations** which are related fall in the same class.
2. DON'T expose the internals of the class to the outside world. Instead **provide a interface** to the world to use the class.
3. If you define some instance variable check if it follows the **has-a relationship**
4. If you inherit the class from some super class check if it follows the **is-a relationship**

Answer (score 0):

```
  using System; 
   using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
   using System.Linq; 
  using System.Text;
     namespace Assignment13
    {
     class Car
{
    int speed = 0;
    double temp =0;

    private int Speed;

    public void setSpeed(int speed)
    {
        this.speed = 50;
    }
    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    private double Temp;
    public void setTemp(double temp)
    {
        this.temp = 70.5;
    }
    public double getTemp()
    {
        return temp;
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car ford = new Car();
        ford.setSpeed(50);
        ford.setTemp(70.5);
        Console.WriteLine("Speed = " + ford.getSpeed());
        Console.WriteLine("Temp = " + ford.getTemp());

        Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. You have defined two "Speed" variables in the class, but you can only declare a variable name once per scope.

   ```
   int Speed = 50;
   double Temp =70.5;

   private int Speed;
   ```
2. Setters are used to assign values, and they should always have one argument, and that argument should be used to assign an instance or class variable.  Here is a corrected version of "setSpeed".

   ```
    public void setSpeed(int speed)
    {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
   ```

In this case, you are ignoring your parameter "speed" and assigning this.speed to a constant value.  This kind of default assignment should be done in a constructor.

3. This setter is the origin of your error: you have a setter with no parameters, which should be a red-flag.  In this case, you should add 1 parameter, "temp" to setTemp():

   ```
   public void setTemp(double temp) {
       this.Temp = temp;
   }
   ```